How can I get the timezone based on the latitude and longitude using python?
I want to get the timezone of a specific latitude and longitude, but formatted in a specific way. For example, instead of returning America/New_York, I'd like Eastern/Eastern Standard Time/EST. I tried to search the documentation for timezonefinder, but didn't see any options for changing the output. I also haven't found anything online about converting America/New_York to EST. I can always create a dictionary mapping to achieve what I want, but I was hoping there was a more efficient way since I'll be working with more than what is shown in the example below.
Here's my code for a few examples with different timezones.
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

tf = TimezoneFinder()

tz1 = tf.timezone_at(lat=40.4467, lng=-80.0158)
tz2 = tf.timezone_at(lat=39.7439, lng=-105.02)
tz3 = tf.timezone_at(lat=37.403, lng=-121.97)
print(tz1)
print(tz2)
print(tz3)





What I get
What I want




tz1
America/New_York
Eastern, EST, etc


tz2
America/Denver
Mountain, MST, etc


tz3
America/Los_Angeles
Pacific, PST, etc




Or alternatively use zoneinfo as documented.

Note that, for example, America/Denver can be either MST or MDT depending on the day of the year, so it's not possible to infer that information only from lat/long.
